# babel inserts spaces into biblatex citations

Tags: biblatex, babel

I have a document that is written mainly in German. Therefore, setting `ngerman` as the main document language with `babel` is the expected thing to do.

However, of more than a hundred referenced articles only about five are in German and have been published in a German journal, while the vast majority have appeared in US or UK journals. Thus, it makes sense to set `american` as the main language for `biblatex` and use `langid = {ngerman}` for the few German entries. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[american,ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@ARTICLE{pollack.2015,
    author = {Ari Pollack and Bibhu D. Mohanty and Rishi Handa and Patrick M. Looser and Valentin Fuster and Spencer B. King and Samin K. Sharma},
    title = {Preventive Stenting in Acute Myocardial Infarction},
    date = {2015},
    }

@ARTICLE{white.2014,
    author = {Harvey White and Kristian Thygesen and Joseph S. Alpert and Allan Jaffe},
    title = {Universal {MI} Definition Update for Cardiovascular Disease},
    date = {2014},
    }

@ARTICLE{green,
    author = {Herbert Grün},
    title = {Ein Artikel},
    date = {2016},
    langid = {ngerman}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nejm]{biblatex}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    language=american,
    autolang=other}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Hier steht viel Text auf Deutsch und es gibt auch eine deutsche Quelle \parencite{green}. Die meisten zitierten Werke sind aber Englisch geschrieben, so etwa \textcites{pollack.2015,white.2014}.

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Apparently, `biblatex` and `babel` do not play well together. While everything looks fine in the bibliography, the citations are gloriously messed up:

[image: Messed up citations]

If I comment out the line `language=american`, everything looks as expected:
[image]

I tried compiling the document with different bibliography/citation styles, both with and without options set in biblatex.cfg -- but nothing save commenting out the language setting had any effect. Thus, it's pretty obvious that there must be an incompatibility with babel. Any suggestions what I could do?

Edit -- Added list of files produced by `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
scrreprt.cls    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
 document
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
 ngerman.ldf    2013/12/13 v2.7 German support for babel (new orthography)
biblatex.sty    2016/05/14 v3.4 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
  blx-dm.def
    nejm.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
standard.bbx    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
    nejm.bbx    2011/09/09  v0.4: nejm.cbx
numeric-comp.cbx    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
    nejm.cbx
biblatex.cfg
  german.lbx    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 ngerman.lbx    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 english.lbx    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
american.lbx    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
    test.bbl
  t1cmss.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

Comment: 'Works for me' with an up-to-date TeX system. Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the `File list` from the `.log` into the question?

Comment: @JosephWright I use the TeX Live distribution from Debian (unstable). However, after updating to the latest version about one or two weeks ago, I ran into an error with a package I need for my current project (deadline next week!), so I downgraded again. The output from \listfiles is attached to the question.

Comment: I get the same file list, so something is odd here. Can you mail me your complete log (joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk)?

Comment: With an current MiKTeX 2.9 I can compile the given MWE without errors or added spaces, but two warnings (`nejm` uses depricated options for `biblatex`).  I have the following entry in my list file you do not have: `bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel`.   MiKTeX version: `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.5.24)`

Comment: We've tracked this down by e-mail: it's down to local configuration so best treated as off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by local configuration settings so 'localized' to the OPs system.